# Impact of having a lot of Istio Gateways

Tags: kubernetes, istio

As I understand it, Istio Ingress traffic follows this pattern:

> External Load Balancer -> Istio Ingress Gateway -> Istio Gateway -> Virtual Service -> Destination (via Rule)

I am considering creating a separate Istio Gateway for each of my applications and services.  But that will have me ending up with quite a few Istio Gateways.

I have tried to search to see if there is an issue with having a lot of Istio Gateways, but I can't seem to find anything on that.

Alternativly, I could have Istio Gateways scope at a "Product Level" (a product owns several applications and services).  If I went this route I could have the differentiation between the applications and services of a product done at the Virtual Services layer.

But it would make my templating easier if I could have each application / service have its own gateway.

**Are there performance implications to having a Istio Gateway per service/application?**

Comment: What do you mean with "a lot"?

Comment: What external load balancer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more of a digression...

Not sure if many Gateways hurt performance.

As I understand the gateway accomplishes three things for you:

1. Exposes a port
2. Whitelists a host header
3. Offloads TLS cert

If you are using something like the AWS ALB as your external load balancer then it seems redundant to even configure more than one gateway since the ALB does the exact same things then just proxies traffic along to the ingressgateway pods' nodeport.  Set the ingressgateway deployment to NodePort and slap a dummy tls cert on Gateway and have e2e encryption.

*Disclaimer: the above statement assumes your k8s worker nodes are in a private subnet.

If in AWS you can even get fancy and work towards zero trust by putting a client cert on API Gateway then validate that Client cert with an Istio AuthPolicy.

API Gateway (with client cert) --> VPC link --> ALB internal --> Istio Ingress (with client cert AuthPolicy) --> ...

Azure front door also introduces some cool possibilities since you can tag some https traffic coming in with custom headers and then use AuthPolicies or Destination Rules to act upon those headers.

/randomthoughts